# How to send multiple confirmation emails after order-process in HYBRIS?

Tags: email, process, sap-commerce-cloud

How can I send multiple emails after order-process? In my way when I add products to cart and go to cart , I have option to choose some emails. For example before place order I want to send emails and to **test@test.com**, **test1@test.com** and **test3@test.com** confirmation emails. Hybris OOTB has a process for sending email to customer which you are login in storefront. ( For example **lucas@lucas.com** ) . So I'm with Lucas in storefront and now when I place order only **Lucas@lucas.com** recived an email from **customerservices@hybris.com**. I saw in  **GenerateEmailAction.java** this piece of code

```
final List<EmailMessageModel> emails = new ArrayList<>();
emails.addAll(businessProcessModel.getEmails());
emails.add(emailMessageModel);
businessProcessModel.setEmails(emails);
getModelService().save(businessProcessModel);
```

so probably somehow can set multiple emails. One note, when I place order , I already have in orderProcessModel selected emails.

```
orderProcessModel.getOrder().getEmails()
```

which is Collection< String>

Answer (score 1):

In OOTB Hybris email functionality does not support attachment, CC, BCC, multiple toAddress, etc. It should be OOTB, I hope it may come in the latest version.

To solve this, you have to define those custom attributes in BusinessProcessModel to stores the values and access them later in **DefaultEmailGenerationService** service. Also, you have to override the **DefaultEmailGenerationService** to support multiple toAddress.

For more details, follow [hybris-support-multiple-toaddress](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/multiple-toaddress-attachment-in-email-hybris.html).

Comment: Hybris 6.7 supports all the above listed features like attachment, CC, BCC, multiple toAddress, etc. Perhaps @rrusev is using an older version.

Comment: I was talking about the OOTB `GenerateEmailAction`, which internally call `EmialGenerationService` and that does not populate CC, BCC, etc. So we need to override EmialGenerationService to populate those fields and thereafter OOTB `EmailService` has everything in place to send an email with all fields. Not sure about 6.7. Can you please help me with the exact service/action which we can use without overriding anything.

Comment: I just checked the 6.7 version, it's same. you need to override `EmialGenerationService` service as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The variables are available but we need to set them manually by overriding the `DefaultEmailGenerationService`